# Migration from XP to Windows 7 using recovered HD

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to migrate the Windows XP Pro 32 bit operating system, applications etc from a USB external drive which is the recovered hard drive from that failed system to my new desktop computer with Windows7 64 bit system?   In doing so, I would like to set up the new computer with the OS and all general applications on the primary 1TB hard drive while the secondary 1TB hard drive to have nothing else but graphics programs and gaming applications complete with their related files and add-ons.  What will I need to accomplish this task efficiently and economically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... A bit hard to understand what you are asking.

Assuming: You have got a hard drive from a failed system and have placed it in a USB caddy and now want to run its programs on your (new) computer?.

If that is correct, this may be possible for some applications, but not for all.

Many applications require installing which copies registry values, settings, DLL files and more to special locations. You will need to reinstall the applications, however you should be able to install them to the drive.

That being said, I would not recommend using an external drive for application storage. Drive assignments can change and it can cuase problems later on.

If there is anything else you asked/I missed, please say and I will edit/add to this answer.

Comment: Thank you Wil for your quick reply.  Your assumption is correct. As a new user I can see that I must be much more specific in stating my questions.  I have read reviews for programs such as PCmover and ZinstallXP7 and they seem to intimate that it is possible to move all and everything from my recovered drive to the new Windows 7 based computer including registries and the like without missing a stroke, however, I too am doubtful. I am continuing to gather much needed information for the proposed transfer with the hope of accomplishing same with as little pain as possible.